# PHP SOAP Extension with WSDL throwing Headers already sent

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

Acknowledging the fact that this question has been asked a number of times and I haven't come across a solution that is close to my situation I was left with no option but to post my own query.

Below is a simple class I wrote which I convert to a wsdl file through php2wsdl library.

```
class MyClass
{
  /**
   * Adds two numbers.
   *
   * @soap
   *
   * @param float $p1
   * @param float $p2
   * @return float
  */
  public function getSum($num1, $num2){
     return $num1 + $num2;
    }
 }
```

I have includexd below an image of the wsdl file due to formatting issues I might get typing it here so my apologies:

[image]

I have a client that I query this service with but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am aware of all the existing libraries such as Zend_AutoDiscovery and stuff but really want to understand the concepts behind PHP Soap like from scratch.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../php2wsdl.php';
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 600);

try {

  $client = new \SoapClient(__DIR__ . '/../input/myclass.wsdl', array(
     'connection_timeout'=>5,
     'trace'=>true,
     'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2
   ));

 $myClass = new \MyClass();

 /* var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
 exit();*/

 $result =  $client->__soapCall('getSum', array('MyClass' => $class, 'num1' => 17, 'num2' => 5));
 printf("Result = %s\n", $result);

} catch (Exception $e) {
  printf("Message = %s\n",$e->__toString());
}
```

> Warning: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http headers in D:\web\webserv-bundle\web\services\process\myclass_client.php:19 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('http://localhos...', 'http://localhos...', 2, 0) #1 D:\web\webserv-bundle\web\services\process\myclass_client.php(19): SoapClient->__soapCall('getSum', Array) #2 D:\web\webserv-bundle\web\services\index.php(3): require_once('D:\web\webserv-...') #3 {main} thrown in D:\web\webserv-bundle\web\services\process\myclass_client.php on line 19

Answer (score 0):

You should increase your socket timeout.

In your php.ini file,

```
default_socket_timeout = 480
```

also change true to 1,

```
'trace'=>1
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $client->getSum(17, 5);
```

ok, you need 3 file:

1. soap server with MyClass
2. wsdl
3. soap client

---

soap server:
webserv-bundle/web/services/index.php

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    public function getSum($num1, $num2){
        return $num1 + $num2;
    }
}

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$server = new SoapServer("http://path_to_your_wsdl");

$server->setClass("MyClass");

$server->handle();
```

---

wsdl file - you're already have this file

this file must be accessible in browser `http://path_to_your_wsdl`

---

soap client - soapclient.php

```
<?php

$client = new SoapClient(
    "http://path_to_your_wsdl",
    array( 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2)
);

var_dump($client->getSum(55,4));
```

then in browser - http://path_to_my_project/soapclient.php

Comment: Should this call then be left as is $client->__soapCall(...)?

Comment: maybe i don't understand whole question, but try this:
$client = new \SoapClient(..............);
$result = $client->getSum(17, 5);
var_dump($result);

Comment: Basically I am testing out the SOAP class provided by PHP in a WSDL MODE. The wsdl file is not generated by hand but a library that is available in Composer as "php2wsdl/php2wsdl". Now the issue is with testing this wsdl file with PHP SOAP CLIENT class as shown the main question where there is a method in the class that does the calculation of the 2 numbers passed as parameters. How do I test my WSDL file with Client class from PHP SOAP taking the custom class into consideration?

Comment: Without a proper explanation, just posting code isn't really appreciated

Comment: Thanks. I will get back to you once I figure this out. I apologize for the poor explanation I gave.